# how to create database with this script

Tags: sql, asp.net

I want to create database from this scrips

because I lost `CustomersDB.mdf`

I got this script from `model.edmx` in visual studio.

In this way

1.Click right mouse button on model and select Generate Database from Model.

2.Copy generated SQL script.

3.click new query in `MSSQL` and paste code and run it <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>

but does not work.

please help me create database in MSSQL.

Thanks!

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
GO
USE [CustomersDB];
GO
IF SCHEMA_ID(N'dbo') IS NULL EXECUTE(N'CREATE SCHEMA [dbo]');
GO



IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_tbl_User_tbl_Role]', 'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_User] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_User_tbl_Role];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_tbl_Customer_tbl_User]', 'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Customer] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_Customer_tbl_User];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_tbl_Customer_tbl_CatGift]', 'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Customer] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_Customer_tbl_CatGift];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_tbl_darsad_tbl_CatGift]', 'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_darsad] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_darsad_tbl_CatGift];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_tbl_darsad_tbl_User]', 'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_darsad] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_darsad_tbl_User];
GO



IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[sysdiagrams]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[sysdiagrams];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tbl_Role]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Role];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tbl_User]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[tbl_User];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tbl_Customer]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Customer];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tbl_CatGift]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[tbl_CatGift];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tbl_darsad]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[tbl_darsad];
GO



-- Creating table 'sysdiagrams'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sysdiagrams] (
    [name] nvarchar(128)  NOT NULL,
    [principal_id] int  NOT NULL,
    [diagram_id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [version] int  NULL,
    [definition] varbinary(max)  NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'tbl_Role'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Role] (
    [RoleID] int  NOT NULL,
    [RoleTitle] nvarchar(50)  NULL,
    [RoleName] nvarchar(50)  NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'tbl_User'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_User] (
    [UserID] int  NOT NULL,
    [RoleID_FK] int  NULL,
    [Username] nvarchar(150)  NULL,
    [Pass] nvarchar(150)  NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(150)  NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'tbl_Customer'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Customer] (
    [CustomerID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID_FK] int  NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(50)  NULL,
    [Family] nvarchar(50)  NULL,
    [Code] nvarchar(50)  NULL,
    [Mobile] nvarchar(50)  NULL,
    [Price] decimal(18,0)  NULL,
    [Address] nvarchar(250)  NULL,
    [BirthdayYear] nchar(4)  NULL,
    [BirthdayMonth] nchar(2)  NULL,
    [BirthdayDay] nchar(2)  NULL,
    [Tell] nvarchar(50)  NULL,
    [CatGiftID_FK] int  NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'tbl_CatGift'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_CatGift] (
    [CatGiftID] int  NOT NULL,
    [title] nvarchar(50)  NULL,
    [name] nvarchar(50)  NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'tbl_darsad'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_darsad] (
    [DarsadID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID_FK] int  NULL,
    [CatGiftID_FK] int  NULL,
    [DarsadAval] int  NULL,
    [DarsadDovom] int  NULL,
    [Darsadsevom] int  NULL
);
GO




ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sysdiagrams]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_sysdiagrams]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([diagram_id] ASC);
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Role]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Role]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RoleID] ASC);
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_User]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_User]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC);
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Customer]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Customer]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CustomerID] ASC);
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_CatGift]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_CatGift]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CatGiftID] ASC);
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_darsad]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_darsad]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DarsadID] ASC);
GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_User]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_User_tbl_Role]
    FOREIGN KEY ([RoleID_FK])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl_Role]
        ([RoleID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_tbl_User_tbl_Role]
ON [dbo].[tbl_User]
    ([RoleID_FK]);
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Customer]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_Customer_tbl_User]
    FOREIGN KEY ([UserID_FK])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl_User]
        ([UserID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_tbl_Customer_tbl_User]
ON [dbo].[tbl_Customer]
    ([UserID_FK]);
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Customer]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_Customer_tbl_CatGift]
    FOREIGN KEY ([CatGiftID_FK])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl_CatGift]
        ([CatGiftID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_tbl_Customer_tbl_CatGift]
ON [dbo].[tbl_Customer]
    ([CatGiftID_FK]);
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_darsad]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_darsad_tbl_CatGift]
    FOREIGN KEY ([CatGiftID_FK])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl_CatGift]
        ([CatGiftID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_tbl_darsad_tbl_CatGift]
ON [dbo].[tbl_darsad]
    ([CatGiftID_FK]);
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_darsad]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_darsad_tbl_User]
    FOREIGN KEY ([UserID_FK])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl_User]
        ([UserID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_tbl_darsad_tbl_User]
ON [dbo].[tbl_darsad]
    ([UserID_FK]);
GO
```

Comment: You've got to be more specific about "it doesn't work". What errors do you receive (if any).

Comment: @Brien look at this pic [link](https://pasteboard.co/HdoNen6.jpg)

Comment: The database itself does not exist. You are attempting to create objects on a database that isn't there yet. You need to create the database object first, then `USE` it.

Comment: @Brien Thank you so much for your guidance. The problem was solved

Comment: You are welcome @amir - Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for posting your DDL when you started the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database object itself is not created yet. This is the reason you are getting the error:

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Database 'CustomersDB' does not
>   exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

If this is just for testing purposes, this script will get you started. I used SSMS 17.4 for this script.

What I would recommend though is you create the database yourself, choosing all of your own attributes/options.

If using SQL Server Management Studio, you can right-click on the Databases folder and select "New Database...".

[image]

Then find a tutorial and/or browse your options and select the options you want for your own particular use case.

```
CREATE DATABASE [CustomersDB]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'CustomersDB', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\CustomersDB.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'CustomersDB_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\CustomersDB_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 140
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON(INCREMENTAL = OFF)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET  MULTI_USER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 60 SECONDS 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = DISABLED 
GO
USE [CustomersDB]
GO
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION = Off;
GO
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION FOR SECONDARY SET LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION = Primary;
GO
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET MAXDOP = 0;
GO
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION FOR SECONDARY SET MAXDOP = PRIMARY;
GO
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET PARAMETER_SNIFFING = On;
GO
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION FOR SECONDARY SET PARAMETER_SNIFFING = Primary;
GO
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES = Off;
GO
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION FOR SECONDARY SET QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES = Primary;
GO
USE [CustomersDB]
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.filegroups WHERE is_default=1 AND name = N'PRIMARY') ALTER DATABASE [CustomersDB] MODIFY FILEGROUP [PRIMARY] DEFAULT
GO
```